# PHP echo in HTML file

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to output some text stored in a variable in my HTML file

```
    <span class="error">*<?php echo $piIdError;?></span>
```

I have declared and initialized the variable already along with the rest of some other php code that works

```
            if (empty($_POST['piId']))
    {
        $piIdError = "Pi Id is Required";
    }
    else
    {
        $id = $_POST['piId'];
    }
```

but when I run the file I get this error:

> Notice: Undefined variable: piIdError in C:\xampp\htdocs\piWebConfig\index.php on line 86

Anyone have any ideas to what might be happening?

Thanks

Comment: Show us where you initialized the `$piIdError`

Comment: Can you include the while file so that we can see where `piIdError` is defined?

Comment: One line of code isn't enough to properly diagnose the problem. The notice doesn't lie.

Comment: So, basically `empty($_POST['piId'])` yields `false` and therefore you only set `$id` and not `$piIdError`.

Comment: How can he show where he define variable, if it undefined? :)

Comment: Are both pieces op code in the same file? And in which order? Can you provide a complete piece of code, the shortest one you can create to reproduce it? And is $piIdError declared inside the if(), or only assigned?

Comment: Just write on top of file `$piIdError = "";`

Comment: `$piIdError` only gets a value when `$_POST['piId']` doesn't have a value. As soon as you post an id, you will get the error. I think the best solution would be to conditionally render the whole span, since it doesn't make sense to output it when there is no error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just initialize the variable `$piIdError` with the default value like

```
$piIdError = '';
if (empty($_POST['piId']))
{
    $piIdError = "Pi Id is Required";
}
else
{
    $id = $_POST['piId'];
}
```

Because if the condition failes then it goes for the `else` part at where the `$piIdError` was not defined.Orelse you can use `isset` like

```
<span class="error">*
    <?php if(isset($piIdError))
        echo $piIdError;?>
</span>
```

Comment: @vp_arth may be it represents `required` field.

Comment: `error` class can be both required and error messages..they both represent in `red`.

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML code, use `isset()` to check if the variable is declared. You can pair it with a ternary operator, and you're all set:

```
<span class="error"><?php echo (isset($piIdError)) ? $piIdError : ''; ?></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($_POST['piId'] == '') {
    $piIdError = "Pi Id is Required";
} else {
    $id = $_POST['piId'];
}
?>

<?php
if(isset($piIdError)) {
    echo '<span class="error">*'.$piIdError.'</span>';
}
?>
```

Comment: What language you use here? It's not valid php

Comment: you should split `html` from `php` here